# How can i show alphabets on the top of product table

Tags: java

```
public class Producttable {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int tableSize = 4;

    printMultiplicationTable(tableSize);
}

public static void printMultiplicationTable(int tableSize) {

    // first print the top header row
    System.out.format("      ");

    for(int i = 1; i<=tableSize;i++ ) {

        System.out.format("%4d",i);
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("__________________________");

    for(int i = 1 ;i<=tableSize;i++) {
        // print left most column first

        System.out.format("%4d |",i);

        for(int j=1;j<=tableSize;j++) {
            System.out.format("%4d",i*j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Teacher gave us task to make a product table [This is the product table that i am getting with this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIVqY.png)
Everything is good here but instead of numbers on the top head of the table i want alphabets like (A B C D). can anybody help me please?

Comment: What, if anything, have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the following changes:

```
 class Producttable {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int tableSize = 4;

    printMultiplicationTable(tableSize);
}

public static void printMultiplicationTable(int tableSize) {

    // first print the top header row
    System.out.format("      ");

    for(int i = 1; i<=tableSize;i++ ) {

        char c = (char)(64+i);
        System.out.format("%4s",String.valueOf(c));
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("__________________________");

    for(int i = 1 ;i<=tableSize;i++) {
        // print left most column first

        System.out.format("%4d |",i);

        for(int j=1;j<=tableSize;j++) {
            System.out.format("%4d",i*j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A computer only knows how to work with numbers. When you work with letters, underneath, the computer is working with numbers. So it stands to reason that you can work with numbers and transform them into letters with the appropriate code.

Refresh your knowledge of the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), this is what the computer uses to convert numbers into characters.

You could write a loop that started at 65 and stopped at 90, and for each number you could print the character that it corresponds to in the ASCII table. See how I use the `"%c"` format for `printf` to format an integer as a character.

```
for(int i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%c", i);
}
```

Output:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**

`System.out.format("%4d",i);`

**With**

`System.out.format("%4c", i + 'A' - 1);`

Comment: got it!! but as you seen in the picture the numbers on the head are stick to the top i want my alphabets to be on the line not too much away from the line. Kindly help plz

Comment: You have selected an underscore "_" and not a dash "-" to print your line. An underscore always appears at the bottom of the line giving you the impression that the line of the letters above it is away. Use a dash to print your line.

Comment: ok that's fine. one more thing, I want line beneath the letters, I dont want it to be starting all the way before the table. I want line beneath the letters.

Comment: That should be easy. Just replace some (first 6 or 7) dashes with a space .

Comment: @JordanNegative, I thought my answer was the one which helped you the most.

Comment: @JordanNegative, but you marked the other answer correct, not mine.